# AngularJS making dependent variable static

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui.router with AngularJS. I have a resolved dependency in my route here:

```
 .state('root.resume', {
    url: "/resume",
    templateUrl: "resume/index.html",
    title: "Resume",
    controller: "ResumeCtrl",
    resolve: {
      resume: ['ResumeFactory', function(ResumeFactory){
        return ResumeFactory.get().$promise;
      }]
    }
  })
```

I am including the dependency in my controller here:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('controllers.resume', [])
    .controller('ResumeCtrl', [
    '$scope', 'resume',
    function($scope, resume) {

      $scope.resume = resume;
      $scope.resume_2 = resume;

      $scope.cancel = function(obj) {
        $scope.resume[obj] = this.resume[obj];
      }

    }]);
})();
```

In my view, when I make a change to $scope.resume, it also changes $scope.resume_2. Why does this happen? Is there a way I can make it so that $scope.resume_2 will not change based on $scope.resume?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because both `$scope.resume` and `$scope.resume_2` hold the same reference to an object (`resume`), thus, when you change something in that object, both of your $scopes variables will have the change reflected since both have the same reference, you can, however, create a copy with angular:

```
 $scope.resume = angular.copy(resume);
 $scope.resume_2 = resume;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I also appreciate your explanation, I'm always trying to learn more :)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :)